# How to pass configuration to node modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a module `mymodule` that has some configuration `foo`, `bar` and two functions `f1`, `f2`.

I want to initialize this module with the defaults in one of its clients, and pass some other defaults in another.

Something like this:

```
// mymodule.js 
let conf = {}

function f1(opts = {}) {
    let a = conf.foo
    let b = opts.baz
    // do something with a and b
}
function1 f2(opts = {}) {
    let c = conf.bar
    let d = opts.qux
    // something with c and d

}

modul.exports = function(defaults = {foo:'foo', bar:'bar'}) {
    conf = defaults
    return {
        f1,
        f2
    }
}

// client1.js
const mymodule = require('./mymodule')();
...
mymodule.f1();
mymodule.f2();

// client2.js
const mymodule = require('./mymodule')({
    foo:'leFoo',
    bar:'leBar'
});
...
mymodule.f1();
mymodule.f2();
```

The problem of course is, if I do this, I would override the conf from client1 when I'm using client2.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't mind the downvote, would appreciate a comment on the reason (and an answer if possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous ways to achieve this, but the way that is closest to what you've already got is to wrap the entire module in a function:

```
modul.exports = function(defaults = {foo:'foo', bar:'bar'}) {
    let conf = defaults

    function f1(opts = {}) {
        let a = conf.foo
        let b = opts.baz
        // do something with a and b
    }

    function1 f2(opts = {}) {
        let c = conf.bar
        let d = opts.qux
        // something with c and d
    }

    return {
        f1,
        f2
    }
}
```

Now each caller has a privately configured version of the module.